# How to customize render Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am a newbie with Symfony 2.8.
I have this array

```
IndexController.php on line 18:
array:6 [▼
  "code" => "Home"
  "parent" => "master"
  "labels" => array:1 [▼
    "en_US" => "Home"
  ]
  "mainMenu" => false
  "footerMenu" => false
  "headerMenu" => true
]
```

For example: when mainMenu is set to true I need to display mainMenu.html.twig.

With this method I am calling this array

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $locale, $page) {
    $pageContent = $this->container->get("pimc_akeneo_cms_page_content_builder");
    $akeneoConnector = $this->container->get("pimc_akeneo_cms_backend_connector");
    $html = $pageContent->build($page, $locale);

    $elements = $akeneoConnector->getCategoryList($page);

    if($elements['mainMenu'] == true){
        $this->render('base/mainMenu.html.twig'); // I have problem in here
    }
    if($elements['headerMenu'] == true){
        $this->render('base/headerMenu.html.twig'); // I have problem in here
    }
    if($elements['footerMenu'] == true){
        $this->render('base/footerMenu.html.twig'); // I have problem in here
    }

    return $this->render('base/index.html.twig', ["content" => $html]);
}
```

I have headerMenu.html.twig, footerMenu.html.twig and mainMenu.html.twig in base app/Resources/views/base/ . 
This seems like really an easy problem, but I can't resolve it. 
So the problem is the syntax to write when for example mainMenu.html.twig is set to true. How can I display this ?

Comment: use return in every if like return $this->render...

Comment: Yes, I have tried already that. 
And then it returns just for example mainMenu.html.twig and that is not what I want.

Comment: ok, then you need to make this conditional load of template under the  twig view

Comment: Could you be more specific with conditional load ?

Comment: red the doc of include, i belive thats is your needed https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. It is pure include, not in if else condition. Am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157366/discussion-between-nebojsa-komnenovic-and-alvaro-touzon).

Comment: Do it in your Twig template, not in the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `return $this->render()` returns HTTP response in the form of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` instance which is required by every `*Action` methods in Symfony's controllers. Having that 
said you cannot return more than one Responses per request and also `$this->render()` without `return` doesn't have any impact for Symfony.

In your case you should move displaying template logic to the View layer like this:

In your `indexAction`

```
return $this->render('base/index.html.twig', [
    "content" => $html,
    "elements" => $elements // pass this to template
]);
```

In your `base/index.html.twig`

```
{% if elements['mainMenu'] is defined and elements['mainMenu'] is same as(true) %}
    {% include 'base/mainMenu.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

{% if elements['headerMenu'] is defined and elements['headerMenu'] is same as(true) %}
    {% include 'base/headerMenu.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}

etc...
```

Alternatively (only in case when you have multiple alternative templates possible to be rendered in the same DOM's location):

```
{% for tmpl in ['mainMenu', 'headerMenu', 'footerMenu'] %}
    {% if elements[tmpl] is defined and elements[tmpl] is same as(true) %}
     {% include 'base/' ~ tmpl ~ '.html.twig' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So putting that logic in your templates you keep better [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) separation of concerns and now you don't have to repeat that logic in every Controller which Views has those menus to be rendered. You only have to pass `$elements` variable then.